# Electromagnetic Potential in Relativity

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, potential, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations

Studying Special Relativity we discover that Maxwell's Equations can be also written in the following way:
$$\partial _\mu F^{\mu\nu}=\mu_0J^\nu$$
$$dF=0$$
**Where:** $F$ is the [Electromagnetic Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor), $J$ is the [Four-Current Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-current) and $dF$ *to my understanding* is simply a shortcut to write:
$$\partial _\lambda F_{\mu\nu}+\partial _\nu F_{\lambda\mu}+\partial _\mu F_{\nu\lambda}=0$$
Wonderful; **but then** my book goes on to say that since:
$$dF=0$$
We can state that:
$$F=dA$$
and so:
$$F=\partial _\mu A_\nu-\partial _\nu A_\mu$$
where $A$ is defined as the [Electromagnetic Four-Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential). This last bit of reasoning makes no sense to me. Firstly I thought that $dF$ was just an abuse of notation, a shortcut; I cannot see how it can be interpreted as a differential. Secondly even if we take $dF$ as a proper differential why it should then imply that $F=dA$? And even then why on earth $dA$ should be equal to $\partial _\mu A_\nu-\partial _\nu A_\mu$?? I mean, just for starters, where did the minus sign came from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$dF$ is neither a shortcut nor an abuse of notation; it is the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#The_exterior_derivative) of the differential $2$-form $F$.

A $k$-form $G$ with vanishing exterior derivative $(dG=0)$ is called *closed*; a $k$-form which can be written as the exterior derivative of a $(k-1)$-form $(G = df)$ is called *exact*.

It is an elementary result in the theory of differential forms that all exact forms are closed.  That is, if we can write $G= df$, then we are guaranteed that $dG=0$.  However, the reverse is generically true only on [star-shaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) domains$^\dagger$.

---

Since the language of differential forms is new to you, note that you are used to dealing with similar concepts wrapped up in different notation.  The facts (i) that the curl of a gradient is always zero and (ii) that the divergence of a curl is always zero are specific examples of this idea.

Observing that $dF=0$ and concluding that $F=dA$ is spiritually the same as observing that $\nabla \times \mathbf E = 0$ and concluding that $\mathbf E = -\nabla \phi$, or observing that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf B = 0$ and concluding that $\mathbf B = \nabla \times \mathbf A$.

---

$^\dagger$As noted by Michael Seifert in the comments, this result can be extended more generally to [contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space) spaces.

Comment: Ok, I get what you are saying here. But I still don't get why $dF$ has one form and $dA$ another; where did the minus sign came from? Is this a feature of the exterior derivative? If so how?

Comment: $dF$ has six terms upon full antisymmetrization of the three indices, but three of them are unique.

Comment: @Noumeno Yes, it is a feature of exterior derivatives.  A full explanation would be somewhat lengthy and somewhat beyond the scope of your original question.  I would suggest trying to familiarize yourself with differential forms via a more dedicated resource - [these notes](https://www.johnboccio.com/courses/Physics130_2008/forms.pdf) seem to be reasonably accessible - and then post more specific questions you run into (though such questions may be more suited to [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com) ).

Comment: nice answer, but one technical remark: you wrote "However, the reverse is generically true only on simply-connected domains". This isn't quite right (for instance take $U = \Bbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$, and $\mathbf{B}:U \to \Bbb{R}^3$ be given by $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}):=\dfrac{\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{r^2}$ in spherical coordinates. This is a divergence-free vector field on a simply connected domain, yet it doesn't admit a vector potential defined on the whole of $U$; i.e it can't be written as a curl). Poincare's Lemma in $\Bbb{R}^n$ assumes the domain to be star-shaped with respect to some point.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ah yes, thank you! I was writing about Poincare's lemma but then my brain short-circuited to the specific case of $1$-forms.  Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @peek-a-boo:  it’s not strictly necessary that the domain be star-shaped, though.  As an example, consider the vector field you gave, restricted to $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the negative z-axis removed, along with a small ball of finite radius centered at the origin. This *does* admit a vector potential, ie the Dirac monopole solution.   (The removal of the ball is only necessary to make the domain not star-shaped.)

Comment: The full result, IIRC, is that all closed $n$-forms on a domain are exact if all subdomains that are topologically equivalent to $n$-spheres are nulhomotopic, ie they can be smoothly contracted to a point.  If a domain is star-shaped, this is automatically true, but there are also non-star-shaped domains for which this holds.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Interesting, for some reason I was not aware of the generalization to contractible domains.  Thank you!

Comment: @Michael Seifert thanks for pointing out my perhaps misleading phrasing. Of course the domain being star shaped is not necessary (I only intended to say it's a sufficient condition), and it's obvious to see why because we can just take an exact form and restrict it to a smaller open set (disconnected/not simply-connected/ not-star shaped/ not contractible... or whatever, basically restrict to any open subset) then it will still be exact (simply because the exterior derivative plays nicely with taking restrictions of forms).